# AsyncLogin HTTP/OPTIONS request

Tags: identityserver4

On a Magento 1 webshop we have received 6 of these requests from an iPhone, from a known customer:

```
OPTIONS /Home/AsyncLogin?loginHint= HTTP/2.0 405
```

Please advise, could it be related with IdentityServer?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is connected with secure.barion.com